# How to synchronize the display refresh rate with the video frame rate in mpv on Wayland?

Tags: display, video, wayland, mpv

Video content is usually created in 23.976 or 24.000, 24.976 or 25.000 (PAL), 29.970  (NTSC TV) and 59.940 FPS or 60.000 FPS (mainly web video). For even frame-pacing it's vital to adjust the display refresh rate to match the video. mpv scripts have been written for [Xorg](https://gitlab.com/lvml/mpv-plugin-xrandr/) and [Windows](https://github.com/CogentRedTester/mpv-changerefresh). I'm not aware of anything in existence for Wayland, but [an mpv group member claims](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/552#issuecomment-1586370463):

> [issue 'Implement changing refresh rates based on the video's framerate' in the mpv-player/mpv repository]
>
> [...] this differs depending on the compositor. You can easily make one for sway and/or wlroots-based compositors

Can you offer guidance for creating such tool for SwayWM or [wlroots-based compositors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(protocol)#Wayland_compositors)?